# Finding limit of $\frac{e^{-1/x^2}}{x}$

Tags: real-analysis, limits, analysis

I'd like to find the limit of the function $f:\mathbb{R}\setminus \{0\} \to \mathbb{R}, \;f(x):=\frac{e^{-1/x^{2}}}{x}$

as $x \to 0$ utilizing L'Hôpital rule.

If I apply the rule once:

$$ \lim_{x\to 0} f(x) = \frac{\frac{2}{x^{3}}e^{-1/x^{2}}}{1}$$

It looks like the expression is still divergent and I'm stuck. If I applyed the rule again there would be zero in the denominator.

How to preceed from this point?

Comment: You could try substituting $z=\frac{1}{X}$ with $z\to\infty$, and then apply L'Hôpital. Anyway be aware that $e^{-\frac{1}{x^2}}$ is a very tricky ("non-analytical") function so most simple ideas are going to fail.

Comment: More similar/idential questions can be found [with Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%24%5Clim_%7Bx%20%5Cto%200%7D%20%5Cfrac%7Be%5E%7B-1%2Fx%5E2%7D%7D%7Bx%7D%20%24)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

\begin{align}
\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{e^{-1/x^2}}{x} &= \lim_{x \to 0}\frac{1/x}{\exp(1/x^2)}\\
&=\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{-\frac{1}{x^2}}{\exp(1/x^2)(\frac{-2}{x^3})}\\
&= \frac12 \lim_{x \to 0}\frac{x}{\exp(1/x^2)}\\
&=0
\end{align}